# "brought in" vs. "introduced"

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

> We brought in advanced technology from abroad.

Can I change the phrase "brought in" to "introduced" here?

Thank you.

Comment: The meaning is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but it has slightly different implications.

"Brought in" just means that you took technology which was elsewhere and made it available "here".  It might be new technology, or it might be technology people were already aware of, or even used in the past, but just didn't have access to at this point for some reason.

However, "introduced" implies that this is the first time this has ever happened.  That is, that the technology you're bringing in was previously unknown in that place.

Comment: very helpful. thank you